# Only one item of data is coming from Firebase Firestore

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I wrote code like this:

```
  Container(
    height: 250,
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: db.collection("DebrisPeoples").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("yükleniyor");
        } else {
          final List<DebrisPeopleModel> data = snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((e) => DebrisPeopleModel.fromDocument(e))
              .toList();

          inspect(data);
          /*
             OUTPUT:
              [0]: DebrisPeopleModel
              [1]: DebrisPeopleModel
              [2]: DebrisPeopleModel
              [3]: DebrisPeopleModel
              [4]: DebrisPeopleModel
              [5]: DebrisPeopleModel
          */
          for (var item in data)
            return Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(item.nameSurname.toString()),
              ),
            );
        }
        return Container();
      },
    ),
  ),
```

When I print it to the console, data shows up, but when I project it to the screen, only one item of data appears. Why could this be?

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `Card` with a [ListView.builder](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView/ListView.builder.html) instead of using the `for loop`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to return all cards instead of single item like

```dart
 Container(
    //height: 250,
    child: StreamBuilder(
      stream: db.collection("DebrisPeoples").snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) {
          return Text("yükleniyor");
        } else {
         final List<DebrisPeopleModel> data = snapshot.data!.docs
              .map((e) => DebrisPeopleModel.fromDocument(e))
              .toList();
              
          inspect(data);
          List<Widget> cards = [];
          for (var item in data) {
            final card = Card(
              child: ListTile(
                title: Text(item.nameSurname.toString()),
              ),
            );
            cards.add(card);
          }
          return Column(children: cards); // perhaps ListView
        }
      },
    ),
  )
```